# SQL WHEN function - How to fix Syntax Error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am new to SQL coding and I am encountering only one error code so far.
At the second line `WHEN CONVERT`:

(`rd.254` is my table date column)

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) Between 
CONVERT(date,getdate()-7) AND CONVERT(date, getdate()-1) THEN rd.F64 END AS QtyLastWeek

WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) <= CONVERT(date,getdate()-8) THEN rd.F64 END AS Qty2WeeksAgo
```

[image: *Screenshot Here*]

I am trying to find and fix the syntax.

Comment: "rd.254 is my _table_ date _column_"

Comment: Only tag the DBMS you are using ! Either MySQL or SQL-Server. Do not include links. Instead edit your question and include your error statement in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing comma and case

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) Between CONVERT(date,getdate()-7) AND CONVERT(date, getdate()-1) THEN 
   rd.F64 
END AS QtyLastWeek,
CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) <= CONVERT(date,getdate()-8) THEN 
   rd.F64 
END AS Qty2WeeksAgo
```

Answer (score 2):

There is incorrect syntax. If you want to select 2 columns `QtyLastWeek` and `Qty2WeeksAgo` you have to use the comma after `QtyLastWeek` and use another `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,getdate()-7) AND CONVERT(date, getdate()-1) THEN rd.F64 END AS QtyLastWeek,
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) <= CONVERT(date,getdate()-8) THEN rd.F64 END AS Qty2WeeksAgo
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `case` keyword in the second case statement. Try this !

```
CASE WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) Between CONVERT(date,getdate()-7) AND CONVERT(date,getdate()-1) 
THEN rd.F64 
END AS QtyLastWeek,
CASE   WHEN CONVERT(date,rd.F254) <= CONVERT(date,getdate()-8) 
      THEN rd.F64 
END AS Qty2WeeksAgo
```